# PHP - cURL and remote login

Tags: php, curl

I have problem with my script using cURL. On page A, I set cURL POST and send it to page B, where script for login is executed. Data are passed correctly, but session and cookies are not set on page B.

Script login.php open SESSION (and eventually COOKIE) and save neccessary info. If I logged from page B directly, it works fine.

```
    $ch = curl_init("http://www.example.com/login.php");


    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "login_name=xxx&login_pass=xxx");


    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);


    $output = curl_exec ($ch);

    curl_close ($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [COOKIEJAR & COOKIEFILE](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) :

```
<?php
    $ch = curl_init("http://www.example.com/login.php");

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "login_name=xxx&login_pass=xxx");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, '/cookie.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '/cookie.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);


    $output = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close ($ch);
?>
```

You may also create a **tmp** directory where you store the cookie !

Comment: But even if I do that, when I close page A and open page B, I am not logged in

Comment: @MartinPerry That's logical, because the cookie is saved for PHP, if you want to be able to login (from the browser), you have to push that cookie to the client !

Comment: Hm.. but cookie is generated from SESSIONs

Comment: Same problem here. What solution did you find?

Answer (score 0):

try add this to your code

```
$cookie="cookie.txt";
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURL_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURL_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURL_VERBOSE, true);
```

Hope this helpfull..