# POST, GET and cookies via PHP

Tags: php, post, cookies, get

I posted this question earlier but it was misinterpreted by those reading it and was closed before I had time to clarify. If you don't understand what I mean, please ask!

I have a site, let's call it "site A". On "site A", there is a log in page. On this page, you POST a username and password to a PHP script. If the login details are correct, the PHP script sets a cookie on the browser. This cookie is called "SESSION".

When you view the site, it checks whether "SESSION" is valid, and displays either the information or the login page.

I want to connect to the page via PHP and POST the login details. I then want to store the "SESSION" cookie via PHP, and display the contents of the page (again, via PHP).

How would I do this?

Comment: I had to read it a couple of times before it occurred to me that "Site A" is an existing site and the PHP script is on another site, or is at least another page. Is that right? If so, it sounds like you want to build a proxy. Maybe you can look for that term, see of that is indead what you mean.

Comment: @GolezTrol Yes, Site A is an existing site and the PHP script is on another site (site B). I want to connect to site A from the script on Site B, POST the data and then get the cookie information.

Comment: So you want to connect to an external website that gives off a session if you can successfully authenticate to it? Isn't that a job for cURL?

Comment: @DaveChen The external website gives the user a cookie and verifies their login state with this cookie every time. I want to connect to an external website, read the cookie upon the initial connection, and then reconnect with that cookie.

Comment: You're forgetting sessions ;(

Comment: @JamesMonger That should have been the question in the first place. Connect with cURL, read the cookie on login, then on the next connections, use the cookie.

Comment: @DaveChen Thank you! Sorry, I wasn't really sure how to do it and so writing a question was hard. Please post this as an answer so that I can accept it :)

Comment: @JamesMonger I've written something [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13330532)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PHP as a web client as well. You can use the [cUrl library](https://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to make requests from PHP.

You can use [setopt](https://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) to set all kinds op options for your cUrl session, including POST (`CURLOPT_POST`) and the POST variables (`CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`), but also choose a kind of authentication (`CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH`) in case the site doesn't use normal post for this.

I found an example that might be useful here: http://davidwalsh.name/curl-post, although you can find many other examples by Googling for something like 'php curl post'.